# How can I convert a string that represent a HEX octet in postgresql to binary?

Tags: postgresql, binary, hex

I have a mac adress stored with type mac address in postgresql. I need to convert the first octet in the information about I/G bit and U/L bit ([more infos](https://packetsdropped.wordpress.com/2011/01/13/mac-address-universally-or-locally-administered-bit-and-individualgroup-bit/)).

Example: mac address is `AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF`. The first Octet is then `AA`. Converted to Binary: `0101 01010`. The last bit represents I/G: 0. The second from right to left is the U/L bit: 1.

How can I do this in a postgresql query?

This is what I have so far:

```
select id, mac, left(mac::text,2) as octet 
from mytable
```

The return is:

```
id,mac,octet
13,aa:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX,aa
```

I also tried `left(mac::text,2)::integer as integer`, but I get the error message `[22P02] ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "aa"`

The result I want is the following:

```
id, mac, octet, binary, ig_bit, ul_bit
13, aa:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX,aa, 1010 1010, 0, 1
```

So I have isolated the first bit, however, the format is 'text' and I can't convert it to integer or binary.

Comment: I found this in the pg mailing list: [hex_to_int](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/A178A369C8334C29A1365310C41B58DD%40DELLM4500)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [bit strings:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-bit.html)

```
with my_data(mac) as (
    values ('AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF'::macaddr)
)

select 
    mac,
    ('x' || left(mac::text, 2))::bit(8) as octet,
    substr(('x' || left(mac::text, 2))::bit(8)::text, 8, 1) as ig_bit,
    substr(('x' || left(mac::text, 2))::bit(8)::text, 7, 1) as ul_bit
from my_data

        mac        |  octet   | ig_bit | ul_bit 
-------------------+----------+--------+--------
 aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff | 10101010 | 0      | 1
(1 row)
```

You can also use the function [`get_bit()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-bitstring.html), e.g.:

```
with my_data(mac) as (
    values ('AA-BB-CC-DD-EE-FF'::macaddr)
),
octet as (
    select mac, ('x' || left(mac::text, 2))::bit(8) as binary_octet
    from my_data
)

select 
    mac,
    binary_octet,
    get_bit(binary_octet, 7) as ig_bit,
    get_bit(binary_octet, 6) as ul_bit
from octet
```

Note, that the index of the leftmost bit is 0.